# Can't return values, "StaleElementReferenceException"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a link which I want to open in a new tab, **scrape** some data out of it and then close that tab. I am calling a function **print_code()** from a loop to solve this. From that function **print_code()**, I want to return 2 values, but whenever I do it, I get **StaleElementReferenceException** in the loop. When I am not returning any values, I am able to print both values in the **print_code()** function without any errors. What should I do?

```
def print_code(s):
    temp_driver=driver. //did this because when using driver, I was again getting the same exception
    temp_driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    temp_driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    temp_driver.get(s)
    problem=temp_driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    problem_number=problem[2].text.split(' ')[0]
    print(problem_number) //I am able to do this
    code=temp_driver.find_element_by_class_name("linenums")
    temp_driver.close()
    temp_driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    return [problem_number,code.text];

for i in range(0,4):
    print(table_rows_array[i])
    link=driver.find_element_by_link_text(source_array[i].text)
    link2code=link.get_attribute("href")
    print(link2code)
    arr=print_code(link2code) //this throws exception
    print(arr[0])
    # print(file_name)
```

Edit: I tried a different way. I appended both, i.e. **problem_number** and **code.text** to a list in **print_code()** and returned the list back. It's working perfectly. I don't know why the above code is not working.

Comment: Have you tried webdriver wait to resolve your issue? StaleElementReferenceException is occurs when element ref. is not attached to DOM. Try to use explicit wait to resolve your issue

Comment: No it is not working, I think there is some issue with defining list on return statement. I am not very much familiar with intricacies of Python, so not sure.

Comment: I think the problem occurs because you are switching windows, then trying to reference the text attribute of the code element. Perhaps try setting     code=temp_driver.find_element_by_class_name("linenums").text and then return code, instead of returning code.text

Comment: @Sri I tried to do what you said, I am now able to return both values. But from my calling function, I am still not able to extract text out **code**. On extracting text out it, it's giving me the same exception.